# R2 for oscillating data

Tags: correlation, goodness-of-fit, academia

First question on here.

I am working on master's research and I am trying to get a goodness of fit for my experimental data. I have calculated and plotted fit lines using the polyfit function in matlab, shown in the image for one of my cases. These are linear ($y=ax+b$, yellow) and quadratic ($y=ax^2+bx+c$, red). The plot is log base on the x axis, so it doesn't appear that way in the image. The blue is the experimental data with a line simply connecting the points. I don't want to change the fits because I don't want to include the oscillations, because they came from the calculations to get this data rather than the actual experiments.

[image: Experiment Data with two different fits]

X axis: Kinetic Energy (J/kg) - Y axis: Depth (m)

My goal is to show that the fit line fits the data decently well and I want a quantitative value for that. I calculated the $R^2$ value for the two different lines and it is 0.464 and 0.490 for linear and quadratic respectively. I feel like the data trends better than the $R^2$ indicates, but due to the oscillating nature of the data, the $R^2$ is relatively weak.

As far as other options, I have considered using average error, but I feel like that gives me a relatively arbitrary value. I have looked into calculating the frechet distance, but from my understanding of it, the frechet distance is similar to the average error in that it's a value of how far they deviate, but looks to the closest value in any direction.

My advisor prefers the simplicity of understanding of $R^2$, rather than a value such as error. Is there a version of $R^2$ that accounts that the variation occurs equally on either side of the fit line? Something along the lines of a total $R^2$ rather than an absolute value one? Thanks!

From the comments I will try to explain what this data is and what I'm looking for. This is the energy of a wave vs. height in a tank. So as you go down in depth (closer to the bottom) the energy of this wave is decreasing. Looking at the theory for this situation, it is smooth, but due to local variations, we get oscillations in the experimental data. I am hoping to find some metric that will tell the reader that the trend line matches the data's trend well.

Comment: Well the fit line *doesn't* fit the data "well". The data are "oscillating". Maybe you should redefine what a good fit means in this case.

Comment: I've seen these kinds of plots in ecology before, and so the "oscillation" could be some kind of seasonal trend. But you haven't labeled your axes! (always label your axes... with units!). Very often, the variation around a line of best fit spuriously appears to "oscillate" when you connect the points by a trendline. That's just the power of suggestion. Time series data, though, often have seasonal components. Advanced modeling techniques are out there to "deseason" trendlines.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I have updated the question with axes for the plots and a further explanation of the data. I connected the points because they represent real placement in a tank, but I could remove it if you think it's more clear that way.

Comment: Which axis is which? Most likely energy is on the horizontal axis which you are calling "y." Without clearly labeling the axes, almost all readers will assume energy is on the *vertical* axis, which completely changes our impression what you are doing.

Comment: Consider deseasonalizing the data and then running your calculation.

Comment: @kylejh wouldn't the relation between the energy of a wave and the depth of a tank follow a theoretical model?